# How to look ahead into a file?

Tags: r

I'm asking myself and you how to look ahead into a file without reading it. At a first glance the `seek` function seems to be appropriate. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seek.html) says:

> seek with where = NA returns the current byte offset of a connection
>   (from the beginning), and with a non-missing where argument the
>   connection is re-positioned (if possible) to the specified position.

But at the end of that page I found the following warning:

> Use of seek on Windows is discouraged. We have found so many errors in
>   the Windows implementation of file positioning that users are advised
>   to use it only at their own risk, and asked not to waste the R
>   developers' time with bug reports on Windows' deficiencies.

So is there any save way to look ahead?

Comment: What about `scan(file="c:/temp/R/data.txt", skip = 5, nlines = 1)`

Comment: `scan` seems to shift the position of the read pointer, so I can't read the skiped lines and the scanned lines later.